# Override equals and cast object to string

Tags: java, object, vector, compare

EDIT: the question is why cant I use ".contains" (override .equals() in the object) to compare object attributes (a string) instead of comparing the object itself.
Thanks JB:
Turns out I was confusing overriding compareTo() with overriding equals()

EDIT: 
QUESTION REDEFINED:

Why cant I override equals to compare strings in my object:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj){
  ...
  if(obj instanceof String){
    String testString = (String) obj;
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

Or even overload for that matter:

```
public boolean equals(String stringObj){
  ...  
}
```

I read somewhere that the compiler doesn't use logic to decide this, it uses types. So if I then call `myObj.equals(stringOne + "_" + stringTwo)` shouldn't this work as it knows a string is being passed?
Thanks,
Steve.

Answer (score 1):

Why this code doesn't make sense:

1. because Comparable is supposed to respect rules: if `a < b` is true, then `b > a` must be true. You can compare an instance of your class with String, but a String can't compare with an instance of your custom class. You're thus breaking the contract of Comparable
2. because Vector doesn't use `compareTo()` to check if an element exists or not. It uses `equals()`.
3. Because you shouldn't alter the nature of a class just to implement a specific use-case consisting in adding instances of this class to a list and check for duplicates. This logic should be outside of the class. You could simply loop through the list and check is an instance with the item and position already exists or not, before creating your custom class instance.
4. because you shouldn't use Vector for many years (since Java 2 - we're at Java 8). And since it seems the goal is to avoid duplicates, what you should use is a `Set`.

Do the right thing, and use a HashSet. Make sure CustomClass implements `equals()` and `hashCode()` correctly. You could also use a `HashMap<CustomClassKey, CustomClass>`, where CustomClassKey is a simple class containing the two fields identifying your CustomClass instances.

Comment: Thanks for the advice JB, I think I was confusing the term "comparing objects" and the method "compareTo", silly how the mind works sometimes. Overriding equals does exactly what I want it to (compare objects based on specific contained attributes). I specificity avoid using non duplication collections here because I will most likely never have a "real" duplicate, but having the same "item" and "position" values is considered a duplicate in the system. I just needed to redefine how ".contains" worked. Sorry I thought that was obvious (editing question for future readers).